# Display data from the past week (a billion-row database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am making a web app, using ASP.NET. Basically, I need to display data from a SQL Server, which has a billion-row database. When I query something, it often takes a lot of time. For example, I used this codes to query data created from the past week:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate as DateTime,
        @PastWeek as DateTime;

SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE();
SET @PastWeek = DATEADD(ww, -1, @CurrentDate);      

SELECT [ID]
      ,[TIMESTAMP]
      ,[USERNAME]
      ,[CLIENTNAME]
      ,[COMMAND]
      ,[PATH]
  FROM [P4D] WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN @CurrentDate AND @PastWeek;
```

It is still querying after 20 min. I think it takes long because it tests every single row whether it is in the time range or not.

Is it the wrong way to pull data created from pastweek? Or are there any ways making the query statements more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an index on `TIMESTAMP`? Is your query using it? What proportion of the table qualifies?

Comment: How many rows do you expect to return for this type of query?  With an index on TIMESTAMP this query should be relatively fast. (I'm assuming that TIMESTAMP is actually a DATETIME column).

Comment: If you have a large table, but are primarily concerned with the most recent data, then you should look into partitioning the data.  This will give you much faster access to the most recent data for all columns.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I am not sure if I have the index on TIMESTAMP.
-LarryLustig: Yeah, It is a DateTime column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - partitioning is primarily an administrative benefit (for switching data in and out) not a performance one (though it might well mean less blocking from avoiding need for large DML statements). A covering index with leading column `timestamp` is just as good as a partition for retrieving data meeting a particular date range.

Comment: So actually I have an index on ID (COMMAND_ID), not TIMESTAMP. There are lots of recurrences in TIMESTAMP column, like at one point 2000-10-01 00:12:11 AM, there are dozens of activities recorded.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . The point of partitioning is that only the partitions that meet the conditions of the partitioning function need to be scanned.  For partitions defined by TIMESTAMP ranges, in this case, one one or a few partitions would need be scanned. This can result in a huge performance gain for these queries, without incurring the memory overhead of an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things you need:

```
SELECT ID 
      ,TIMESTAMP
      ,USERNAME 
      ,CLIENTNAME 
      ,COMMAND
      ,PATH
  FROM P4D (NOLOCK) WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN @CurrentDate AND @PastWeek;
```

(Add a nolock to your query)

And add a non clustustred index with `TIMESTAMP` and add the selected columns `(ID,USERNAME,CLIENTNAME,COMMAND,PATH)` to this index.

Comment: A little warning: This index will be very big. Make sure there is space enough for it. And it will take some time to create....

Comment: I have a followup question. What happen if I create an index for an existing column? Is it gonna affect my existing table in anyway? Since this is kinda of important database, I just want to make sure. 

Also, is it true that when I create an additional index, now it will take longer to update the table?

Comment: and since you suggest adding all columns in the table to the Timestamp's index, why shouldn't I create a clustered index to increase its performance? Thanks!

Comment: Technicly you are right, but because you are adding the selected columns to the index, it will "techically" make an index that contains the select you need. Your select dont need to lookup in the datafields to get the data, but can get the whole data only from the index. And that make the select realy fast. If you make the TIMESTAMP as an clustered index, it will have to wrtie the added columns to this index another place on the disk. Every index makes insert/deletes/updates "slower", but compared to the select you also need to do, it will be the way to do it (sorry english not main language)

Comment: By the way. If you have a lot of updates in your tables, you might want to set the Fill-factor to 50 or maybe lower. This will take up more space on the disk, but will give you better performance, because the index have some space to "grow/work/adjust" (or what the right word would be)